# MSTest v2 : Deployment directory set to bin directory

Tags: mstest, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm using MSTest v2 with .net6 (vs2022) and i'm running into a problem concerning the deployment of my test files. For a bit of context, i'm migrating a project that was running with .net framework 4.7 that has a ton of deployment files to .net6

What I found is that the TestContext that's injected into my AssemlyInitialize doesn't have the same values for *DeploymentDirectory* and *TestDeploymentDir*.

***Framework4.7***

```
DeploymentDirectory = .../TestResults/Deploy..../Out
TestDeploymentDir = .../TestResults/Deploy..../Out
```

***net6***

```
DeploymentDirectory = .../bin/Debug/net6.0
TestDeploymentDir = .../bin/Debug/net6.0
```

In both cases, every other directories from the TestContext (like *ResultsDirectory* or *TestRunDirectory*) do not change.
I've been looking around but didn't find any way to configure this, or, for that matter, why did this change occur.

I tried to add a .runsettings file with the follwing, but it didn't work

```
<MSTest>
    <DeploymentEnabled>true</DeploymentEnabled>
```

Help appreciated